# use of marvin framework for image/video processing using java code

Tags: java, image-processing, video-processing, marvin-framework

I have a set of `marvin sample projects`. Image processing modules are working well.

But, when I am trying to run a video processing project it raises a exception as follows:

```
Video Format not found Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) uses JavaCV as camera and media file interface. You need to install and configure JavaCV before running these examples, as shown in the posts below.

- [Setup JavaCV in Windows](http://anshulkatta.blogspot.in/2013/04/setup-javacv-in-windows.html)
- [Using JavaCV in MarvinFramework](http://anshulkatta.blogspot.in/2013/04/using-javacv-in-marvinframework.html)

Instead of using MarvinSamples project, use MarvinProject project which includes all project and a newest version of the examples.

If you need any help you can post your questions here on Stackoverflow or on the [Marvin Discussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/marvin-project)